# Keyboard navigation in jQuery : two presses instead of one

Tags: jquery, keyboard

I have a keyboard navigation on my page who permit to navigate between the ".layout" classes. The problem is that after the first start of the page it's necessary to press twice the "down" arrow key to trigger the movement of the page. What's wrong ?

Press : "up" and "down" on your keyboard to see : http://jsfiddle.net/Xroad/LPvS9/4/

PS: I have to keep **"#page"** instead of **"html,body"** otherwise the code comes into conflict with other functions.

```
$(function(){
    var  positions = []
    $('.layout').each(function(){
       positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset().top));
    })
    console.log(positions)
    var count=-1
    var x=positions.length-1    
    $(window).keydown(function (event) {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            if(count>=x*(-1)&&count!==0){   
                count--
                console.log(count)
                $('#page').stop().animate({scrollTop:positions[count]},700);
                }else{event.preventDefault()}

            break;

        case 40:
            if(count<=x){
                count++
                console.log(count)
                $('#page').stop().animate({scrollTop:positions[count]},700);
                }else{event.preventDefault()}

            break;
        }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you initialize

```
var count=-1
```

rather do

```
var count=0
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's perfect. Do you know how to set the position of the page 10px (or other dimension) above each ".layout" ?

Comment: change line 4 to        `positions.push(parseInt($(this).offset().top)-10);`